# Wordpress category filters as subcategories

Tags: categories, widgets

I want to develop a course database available in certain countries. Name of country will be set as top most category name. Then it will be sub-categorized alphabetically, subject, degree level and some other parameters.

The question is, when showing archive of specific country (top most category) how can I set filters so user may get filtered result (alphabetically, degree level etc) of only same country.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to fit complex structure into categories, you should look into creating appropriate [custom taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies), which will give you flexible querying with [taxonomy parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).